# How to unlink customers/users from WooCommerce orders

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I had a failed customer/order import when I upgraded a WooCommerce site.

Customers are now logging in and seeing orders and customer information for random orders - not their own. It is a catastrophe!

I am thinking that a solution might be to unlink all customers from orders and forcing customers to be manually relinked on request.

Problem is - I have an unverified problem whereby one customer recreated a user and on login, had been "magically" linked to another customers order details - so even creating new users seems to be problematic.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

This is a possible explanation of your problem. The customer for an order is saved in the the wp_postmeta table with the meta_key '_customer_user'. This integer is a reference to 'ID' column of wp_users. I think your import broke this relationship. Did your import change user id's? If so you need to remap all the '_customer_user' meta_values to their corresponding new user ids.

If you want to just unlink orders from customers I would try setting this field to 0 or maybe to 1 which would mean that initial user (sysadmin) would now be the customer for all orders. If you do this remember to keep a record of the original '_customer_user' so you can try and recover the correct id later.